# How to remove or replace <strike>Top</strike> Tab Bar View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift

For UX purposes, I want to use images for navigation instead of system badges. Changing the <strike>Top</strike> Tab Bar View Navigation buttons [failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iFZC.png) me once. Now I am trying to remove the bar completely and use image buttons instead.

I have looked at other questions similar, but all askers want to keep the <strike>Top</strike> Tab bar view controller in certain cases.

[image: <strike>Top</strike> Tab Bar View Controller -- the images above will replace the bar]

Can I disable the tab bar in iOS completely and use the images instead?

How do I disable it?

edit: correction - tab bar not top bar + wording and grammar

Comment: That looks like a Tab Bar, not a Top Bar, is that what you mean?

Comment: you're totally right, i am editing the question to correct that!